# iOS UITableView contents not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In a VC I have 2 tableViews - 1 main and other is added in a drop down menu. From drop down menu TableView "`ddTableView`", I have added 5 `cells` in Storyboard itself as prototype cells. Each `cell` contains an `image` and a `Label`. Have also set identifier for each `cell`. Have also set Accessory Type as "Disclosure Indicator" for each `cell` of `ddTableView`.

DataSource and Delegate for mainTV is set to the VC and delegate for ddTableView is set the VC. As the rows are added within the storyboard, I didn't set any datasource for `ddTableView` in my `VC`. I managed my delegate methods like this :-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   if (tableView == ddTableView) {
      // RETURNS NIL ???
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];  
      NSLog(@"CELL Identifier = %@", cell.reuseIdentifier);

      return cell;
   } else {
   }
}
-(void )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (tableView == ddTableView) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog (@" CELL Clicked of - %@", cell.reuseIdentifier);
  }
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (tableView == ddTableView)
    return 44;
else
    return 60;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (tableView == ddTableView)
    return 5;
else
    return [chatMsgsArr count];
}
```

It does call respective delegate method. For `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it returns cell as nil. Why so ? And on execution, I don't see any contents of the table view - table is blank. I changed the bg color of image and text color also, but yet nothing is seen on execution.

Why so ? Where I may be going wrong ?

Comment: is your database nil or try the same code with hardcoded data from an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allocate the cell, the first time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called. If the cell is not allocated it would return `nil` as you are getting right now.

What you need to do is allocate the cell only once, the first time you enter `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. After that you can reuse it as you have done.

If you are planning to use the default `tableViewCell` your method should look as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"your_cell_identifier_name";

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    else
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    //write the code to populate your cell with data here

    //return the cell object
    return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";


  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;


}


   if (tableView == ddTableView) {

  NSLog(@"CELL Identifier = %d", indexpath.row);


 } else {

 NSLog(@"CELL Identifier = %@", [chatMsgsArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
 }
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Karthik, with this code added also the table contents ar not visible. didSelectRowAt method returns "cell" for each cell of the table I click on. I expect it to return the unique identifier that I have set in the storyboard for each cell.